# SSRS SELECT ALL emulation in ASP.NET Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I have a multi-value parameter for SSRS report.
This parameter being a multi-select will have SELECT ALL option that selects all values under the drop down list.
Challenge is emulating the same using ASP.NET drop down list as parameter source.  I will use reportviewer control just to render and display report but not to show parameters.  Parameters come from ASP.NET page. How do I achieve SELECT ALL functionality in this case?

[image]

Comment: do you want it to default to select all? Because in that case you can set the default values for the parameter (I would do this in BIDS).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in query to retrieve dummy record and do `UNION`.
Just do a very simple thing showed below.

```
Select 0 as ID, "(Show All)" as Name
Union
Select Id, Name from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jquery widget to do something like this. For example see Eric Hynds jQuery UI Mutliselect:
http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

It has a 'select all' option

Comment: How would that be implemented in SSRS?

Comment: @Jim OP is building their own front-end for SSRS, so they would read the values from the control and then pass that to SSRS via web service or ReportViewer control. See http://www.codeulike.com/2012/09/crisscross.html for example of something similar.